# Auto-Renewable Subscriptions questions

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have this:

1. User logs in the app (our backend)
2. User subscribes (auto-renewable subscription) -> send receipt to my server for verification > (if verified) content is unlocked
3. Now in my app Subscriptions screen user only sees manage button which leads to the apple subscription   interface (https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions)
4. User changes the APPLE ID in the device and opens the app logged in as the SAME user in our backend.

How to understand that the subscription that were made for this account (our backend acc) was made with another APPLE ID so in the subscription screen we dont show the manage option.

Comment: You can't find any details about the iTunes account that was used for a purchase or is currently signed in. Simply show the manage option regardless. It will open the manage screen for the currently signed in iTunes user but that is not your concern

Comment: Agree with the other comment. If you aren't already manage the subscription purely through the app user account. If they change their apple id it doesn't matter.